# Which JavaScript framework would be better to be used for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I have been using jQuery for all my projects in PHP, Java etc. but now since I am starting up with Rails, I am bit confused about whether to stick with jQuery or use Prototype. Since Rails by default supports Prototype, is there any added advantage in using Prototype? Would it be fine if I use jQuery? Which JavaScript framework do you guys normally use?

Comment: the one you prefer, Rails is agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype came first but jQuery won the JavaScript framework wars. Rails 3 ships with jQuery by default, not Prototype. Use jQuery—it's pretty much the industry standard now.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery will now be the default javascript framework in new version of rails. jQuery is best without any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 is framework agnostic, just use whatever you prefer. I use Jquery.